# Decrypt obfuscated perl script

Tags: linux, perl, security, spam

Had some spam issues on my server and, after finding out and removing some Perl and PHP scripts I'm down to checking what they really do, although I'm a senior PHP programmer I have little experience with Perl, can anyone give me a hand with the script here:

http://pastebin.com/MKiN8ifp

(It was one long line of code, script was called list.pl)

---

The start of the script is:

```
$??s:;s:s;;$?::s;(.*); ]="&\%[=.*.,-))'-,-#-*.).<.'.+-<-~-#,~-.-,.+,~-{-,.<'`.{'`'<-<--):)++,+#,-.{).+,,~+{+,,<)..})<.{.)-,.+.,.)-#):)++,+#,-.{).+,,~+{+,,<)..})<*{.}'`'<-<--):)++,+#,-.{).+:,+,+,',~+*+~+~+{+<+,)..})<'`'<.{'`'<'<-}.<)'+'.:*}.*.'-|-<.+):)~*{)~)|)++,+#,-.{).+:,+,+,',~+*+~+~+{+<+,)..})
```

It continues with precious few non-punctuation characters until the very end:

```
0-9\;\\_rs}&a-h;;s;(.*);$_;see;
```

Comment: Looks like normal Perl to me... are you sure this script isn't a commercially licensed purposely-obfuscated one? We're not here to help you violate licensing agreements.

Comment: I would be interested to know if that does something, but I don't really want to run it at work. It reminds me of one of [these](http://www.cpan.org/misc/japh)

Comment: Even a fairly experienced Perl programmer would cringe faced with trash like that.  It doesn't much matter what it does; it is horrible code.

Comment: @MarcB that would be really sneaky wouldn't it? Make it plain if you can and don't tell me the result if it looks "commercial"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that was used to send spam from my server I'm interested to find out if it's connected to others, yes it's horrible, like I said I de-obfuscated the PHP ones.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Replace the `s;(.*);$_;see;` with `print` to get [this](https://gist.github.com/1989001#file_decoded1.pl). Replace `s;(.*);$_;see;` again with `print` in the first half of the payload to get [this](https://gist.github.com/1989001#file_decoded2.pl), which is the decryption code. The second half of the payload is the code to decrypt, but I can't go any further with it, because as you see, the decryption code is looking for a key in an envvar or a cookie (so that only the script's creator can control it or decode it, presumably), and I don't have that key. This is actually reasonably cleverly done.

Comment: A co-worker points out that if the code was still running, one could do `cat /proc/<pid>/env` and probably find out what the encryption key was (via `E_KEY` or `HTTP_COOKIE`).

Comment: @The Coder - was this script visible under your server root? If you want to pursue this further, maybe you want to put a new script in its place to capture the key.

Comment: I'd say it's _quite_ clever if not very helpful. ;-)

Comment: Looks similar to Mirai to me, an ukrainian perl trojan, wandering through small web devices.
Definitely very tricky

Answer (score 18):

For those interested in the nitty gritty... The first part, when de-tangled looks like this:

```
$?  ?  s/;s/s;;$?/ :
       s/(.*)/...lots of punctuation.../;
```

The `$?` at the beginning of the line is the pre-defined variable [containing the child error](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$CHILD_ERROR), which no doubt serves only as obfuscation. It will be undefined, as there can be no child error at this point.

The questionmark following it is the start of a ternary operator

```
CONDITION ? IF_TRUE : IF_FALSE
```

Which is also added simply to obfuscate. The expression returned for true is a substitution regex, where the `/` slash delimiter has been replaced with colon `s:pattern:replacement:`. Above, I have put back slashes. The other expression, which is the one that will be executed is also a substitution regex, albeit an incredibly long one. The delimiter is semi-colon.

This substitution replaces `.*` in `$_` - the default input and pattern-searching space - with a rather large amount of punctuation characters, which represents the bulk of the code. Since `.*` matches any string, even the empty string, it will simply get inserted into `$_`, and is for all intents and purposes identical to simply assigning the string to `$_`, which is what I did:

```
$_ = q;]="&\%[=.*.,-))'-,-# .......;;
```

The following lines are a [transliteration](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#y/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) and another substitution. (I inserted comments to point out the delimiters)

```
y; -"[%-.:<-@]-`{-}#~\$\\;{\$()*.0-9\;\\_rs}&a-h;;
#^                       ^           ^          ^
#1                       2                      3
```

(1,2,3 are delimiters, the semi-colon between 2 and 3 is escaped)

The basic gist of it is that various characters and ranges `-"` (space to double quote), and something that looks like character classes (with ranges) `[%-.:<-@]`, but isn't, get transliterated into more legible characters e.g. curly braces, dollar sign, parentheses,`0-9`, etc.

```
s;(.*);$_;see;
```

The next substitution is where the magic happens. It is also a substitution with obfuscated delimiters, but with three [modifers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer): `see`. `s` does nothing in this case, as it only allows the wildcard character `.` to match newline. `ee` means to evaluate the expression twice, however.

In order to see what I was evaluating, I performed the transliteration and printed the result. I suspect that I somewhere along the line got some characters corrupted, because there were subtle errors, but here's the short (cleaned up) version:

```
s;(.*);73756220656e6372797074696f6e5f6 .....;;  # very long line of alphanumerics
s;(..);chr(hex($1));eg;
s;(.*);$_;see;
s;(.*);704b652318371910023c761a3618265 .....;;  # another long line
s;(..);chr(hex($1));eg; 
&e_echr(\$_);
s;(.*);$_;see;
```

The long regexes are once again the data containers, and insert data into `$_` to be evaluated as code.

The `s/(..)/chr(hex($1))/eg;` is starting to look rather legible. It is basically reading two characters at the time from `$_` and converting it from hex to corresponding character.

The next to last line `&e_echr(\$_);` stumped me for a while, but it is a subroutine that is defined somewhere in this evaluated code, as hobbs so aptly was able to decode. The dollar sign is prefixed by backslash, meaning it is a reference to `$_`: I.e. that the subroutine can change the global variable.

After quite a few evaluations, `$_` is run through this subroutine, after which whatever is contained in `$_` is evaluated a last time. Presumably this time executing the code. As hobbs said, a key is required, which is taken from the environment `%ENV` of the machine where the script runs. Which we do not have.

Answer (score 6):

Ask the [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) module to make it (a little more) readable.

Comment: I tried that on the code (which Perl said was OK when I checked with `perl -c list.pl`); DeParse didn't want to have anything to do with me - or maybe it was the code it complained about.  (`perl -MO=DeParse list.pl` and some minor variants.  The error was `Undefined subroutine &B::DeParse::compile called at (eval 1) line 24.
CHECK failed--call queue aborted.`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's because Deparse is spelled Deparse, not DeParse.

Comment: Thanks - I'm an idiot for not spotting that.  The Deparse'd output isn't a lot easier to understand, though some of the regexes stand out more clearly.