# How does this perl code print that output?

Tags: perl, obfuscation

Can anyone explain how does this code print that output?

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
       my          
      ($j,$        
   a,$p,$h);$      
   j=sub{print(    
  chr($p+=$a->[$   
  h++]));$j};;;$a  
 =[0,        split 
 "[:         \n]+", 
q/43         -002:1
-084         065:13
0001         000005
-0012        -00003
000013   -82 00048 
21:13:-6.00:-76:72 
 -007.:02:00008.00 
  :::-6.00:::013  
  -70:3::-70:.64   
    /];$p=0x4a     
      ;;$h=0;      
$j->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->();
```

### Output:

`Just another perl hacker`

Comment: `perl -d your_script.pl`  may help?

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4271638/perl_cut_off_their_limbs.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a rather straightforward JAPH. The two biggest features of it is the splitting of the data string that makes up most of the "image", and the semi-recursive printing.

This is the code I get when I clean up the formatting

```
my ($j,$a,$p,$h);
$j = sub {
    print( chr( $p += $a->[$h++] ) );
    $j
};
;;

$a = [0, split "[: \n]+",   # the split regex
q/43         -002:1         # input string start: q/ ...
-084         065:13
0001         000005
-0012        -00003
000013   -82 00048 
21:13:-6.00:-76:72 
 -007.:02:00008.00 
  :::-6.00:::013  
  -70:3::-70:.64   
    /];                     # input string end:   .../   
# print Dumper $a;  # <--- this is my line
$p = 0x4a;;
$h=0;      

$j->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->();
```

The first part is the declaration and assignment of the 4 main variables:

### **$j**

`$j` is a code reference that prints a character, then returns a reference to itself. The print consists of a few steps:

1. `$a->[$h++]`     iterates over the `@$a` array, returning one element
2. `$p += ...`      that element is added to `$p`
3. `print chr( $p ... )`  then `$p` is returned to chr() and the resulting character is printed.

Last in the sub block is `$j`, which means each iteration, the return value of the sub will be a reference to itself. This is the part that allows for the semi-recursive feature.

### **$a**

`$a` is a reference to an array that consists of 0 and the result of a split on the input string. Here also a few things are happening in one line of code:

- `q/43   .../` this is a regular `q()` single quoted string with the delimiter slash `/`. It ends right before the closing bracket `]` that denotes the array reference.
- `split "[: \n]+",` this is a split on a character class, repeated 1 or more times. There are extra spaces inside it (which I have removed here) to fill out the space in the JAPH itself. Basically this removes all colon, space and newline and returns the resulting list.
- `$a = [0, ... ]` the list of the split is added to a list of `0` (just one element) and everything is surrounded with brackets to denote an array reference, which is then stored in `$a`.

I assume the list starts with `0` because the code has a one-off error, in that `$p`'s original value is the first letter in the output.

This is the `Data::Dumper` output of `$a`:

```
$VAR1 = [
          0,
          '43',
          '-002',
          '1',
          '-084',
          '065',
          '13',
          '0001',
          '000005',
          '-0012',
          '-00003',
          '000013',
          '-82',
          '00048',
          '21',
          '13',
          '-6.00',
          '-76',
          '72',
          '-007.',
          '02',
          '00008.00',
          '-6.00',
          '013',
          '-70',
          '3',
          '-70',
          '.64'
        ];
```

---

### **$p and $h**

`$p` and `$h` are only numbers, and their role in this is source number for the `chr()` function and iterator for the `@$a` array, respectively.

The last line is the part where the `$j` subroutine is run and the JAPH is printed. The chained `->()` syntax means that the return value of each previous iteration is used for the next execution. And `$j` returns a reference to itself, which makes it a semi-recursive affair, only the values change.

I guess it is similar to doing this:

```
$x = $j->();
$y = $x->();
$z = $y->();
...
```

So lets walk through the first few steps

- `$j->()` the execution
- `$a->[$h++]` `$h` is incremented to 1, returns 0 to the `$a` substript, which returns the first element of `$a`, which is `0`.
- `$p += 0` This `0` is added to `$p`, and this returns the value of `$p` (74) to chr
- `print chr(74)`  this now prints a `J` to standard output
- `$j` is returned.
- `->()` another execution is performed on the return value, so `$j` is run again.
- `$a->[$h++]` `$h` is incremented to 2, returns 1 to `$a` which returns the second element which is `43`.
- `$p += 43` 74 + 43 = 117 is returned to `chr`
- `print chr(117)` this prints `u`

The elements of `$a` are both positive and negative, moving the number where it needs to be. In the end, all the letters printed form: `Just another Perl hacker,`

Here's a rundown on the 10 first executions:

```
p => 74  += 0         =  74 output => chr( 74) J
p => 74  += 43        = 117 output => chr(117) u
p => 117 += -002      = 115 output => chr(115) s
p => 115 += 1         = 116 output => chr(116) t
p => 116 += -084      =  32 output => chr( 32)
p => 32  += 065       =  97 output => chr( 97) a
p => 97  += 13        = 110 output => chr(110) n
p => 110 += 0001      = 111 output => chr(111) o
p => 111 += 000005    = 116 output => chr(116) t
p => 116 += -0012     = 104 output => chr(104) h
```

Comment: @deadlock It was a somewhat interesting algorithm to decode. :)

Comment: @deadlock Don't get me wrong, it was interesting, but compare it to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9591658/725418 It really hurts your eyes when you look at it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Run it with `perl -MO=Deparse` to see what Perl sees:

```
use warnings;
use strict 'refs';
my($j, $a, $p, $h);
$j = sub {
    print chr($p += $$a[$h++]);
    $j;
}
;
$a = [0, split(/[:         \n]+/, "43         -002:1\n-084         065:13\n0001         000005\n-0012        -00003\n000013   -82 00048 \n21:13:-6.00:-76:72 \n -007.:02:00008.00 \n  :::-6.00:::013  \n  -70:3::-70:.64   \n    ", 0)];
$p = 74;
$h = 0;
&$j()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->()->();
```

Basically, `$j` is a sub reference that returns another sub reference and so on. Before returning, it prints a character and moves the "pointer" into the array of characters to print.

Comment: So, do the ASCII values in `$a` correspond to the output? I can't relate.

Comment: Guessing from `chr($p += $$a[$h++])`, they rather correspond to the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Small comment.

The last line in the numbers block should be this

```
-68:3::-70:.64
```

instead of

```
-70:3::-70:.64
```

It needs a -68 to print a period, the -70 was printing a comma.

(The rest of the line, ":3::-70:.64" is just noise. Those numbers are never passed to the anonymous function in $j.)